# Adding multiple criteria to Lucene DrillDownQuery

Tags: java, lucene, faceted-search

I am using Apache Lucene's facet search. Now suppose I have two field gender which will be categoric and height which will be numeric. In my `DrillDownQuery` I am able to add the categoric items any number of times (i.e I can add gender as both male and female) but when I try to add two numeric ranges (i.e height between 140-150 and height between 170-180) it throws me an error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: dimension "Height" already has a drill-down.`
I am using a `NumericRangeFilter` to create `NumericRange` values.

The code I am using is:

```
private final static FacetsConfig config = new FacetsConfig();
DrillDownQuery q = new DrillDownQuery(config);
q.add(key[i], NumericRangeFilter.newLongRange(key[i], Long.parseLong(arr[0]), Long.parseLong(arr[1]), true, true));
```

where key[1] is the name of the attribute (ex Height) and arr[0] and arr[1] contains the lower and upper limit that I want.

Comment: Would you paste some code with what you have so far?